# Под значимые переменные в классе память выделяется в куче?

Tags: c#

Класс - это ссылочный тип, а если в нем есть значимые переменные, то под них память выделяется в куче, как под ссылочный (поправьте, если ошибаюсь).

То есть, можно передать переменную `x` в метод `F1` и  она должна передаться по ссылке без использования `ref`. Тогда непонятно, почему программа выводит **5**, а не **6**.

```
class A
{
    public int x = 5;

    public void F1(int var)
    {
        var++;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.F1(a.x);
        System.Console.WriteLine(a.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что это копия.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Немного неправильно. Память под `x` действительно выделяется в куче, **НО** когда вызывается метод и переменная передается без ключевого слова `ref`, на стеке создается копия значения этой переменной. При модификации значения параметра изменяться будет параметр на стеке, а не в куче. После завершения вызова стек очищается. Поэтому все изменения над этой переменной будут не видны вне метода.

В C# параметры можно передавать по ссылке и по значению. И способ передачи никак не зависит от того, где выделяется память.

В данном случае вы передаете в метод не *ссылку*, а **значение** типа `int`. Ваше предположение бы работало, если вы передавали бы в метод переменную типа `A` (она будет хранить адрес области памяти, и значение будет браться из этой области):

```
public void F1(A a)
{
    a.x++;
}
```